# Vue watch not triggerring on elements in array

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have two components. One of them creates instances of the other one and adds them to an array then I try to watch on it to execute some functions, but it never triggers. My structure looks something like this:

```
const Child = Vue.extend({
  data() {
    triggerMe: false
  },
  methods: {
    triggerSomething: function() {
      console.log('It's called for sure');
      this.triggerMe = true;
    }
  }
});

const Parent = Vue.extend({
  data() {
    children: []
  },
  components: {
    child: Child
  },
  methods: {
    addChild: function() {
      this.children.push(new Child());
      this.children[this.children.length - 1].$watch('triggerMe', _ => console.log('Never called'));
    }
  }
});
```

It works just right if it's the only one. How to fix that?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what you want to achieve. Did tot check the docs on how Vue handles array changes? You might want to try a `deep` watcher https://michaelnthiessen.com/how-to-watch-nested-data-vue/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found is that `$watch` only triggers when component is mounted to some element in document. Other approach is needed:

```
<scipt id="parent-template">
  <child
    @trigger="triggerThat"
  ></child>
</script>

<script>
// in Child
this.$emit('trigger', someData);

// in Parent
methods: {
  triggerThat: function(data) {
    console.log('I can hear you');
    console.log(data);
  }
}
</script>
```